# Why does the clutch of my bike starts slipping?

Tags: clutch, clutch-plate, clutch-cable

I own a bajaj pulser rs200 which is a 200cc bike. I use is daily to go to work and back for about 20km. I usually ride fast and i am always above 7000rpm. I always release clutch rapidly after matching rev to get max accelaration.

So does this make my clutch plate wear out very fast? 1 have changed my clutch plate at about 10000km and now i clutch again starts to slip at 12000 km(2000km after changing the plates).

Whenever i accelerate more and release the clutch, the rpm starts to rise very fast but there is no increase in accelerarion. Te speed seems to be constant so i have to let go the accelerator, get rmp down to 5000 and then the bike starts accelerating again.

So is this the issue of clutch plate or some other part like clutch spring?

Comment: If you are deliberately slipping the clutch to get more acceleration by keeping the revs high that is a sure way to wear it out quickly.

Comment: Your clutch cable could be too tight.

Comment: There should be just a little bit of free play in the clutch lever before it begins to tension the cable.